# Rails pass ID in view to avoid - undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller I've got an action which allows me to replay to original message from inbox:

```
def create
  original_message = current_user.inbox.messages.find_by(id: params[:original_message_id])

  inbox = if original_message.created_at > 3.days.ago 
             original_message.moderator.inbox
          else
             original_message.admin.inbox
          end

  @message = Message.create(
    inbox: inbox
    body: params[:message][:body]
  )
end
```

If the original message will be older than 3 days the reply should goes to the moderator.outbox, in other case - go to the admin outbox.

In `messages/show.html.erb` I've got:

```
<%= link_to "Reply", new_message_path, class: "btn-primary" %>
```

`new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control", rows: 3 %>
    <%= f.submit 'Send Message', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

How to handle that sort of action in a view to fetch this original message id and reply on? With the code above I've got an error:

> undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass

Comment: This error message says, that your message object was not found. Do you pass  existing `original_message_id` in params and do you pass it at all?

Comment: Typo ? your controller create action initializes `original_message` but in the line below you used `orignal_message` (**not** `original_message`) which should result in this error.

Comment: @TiSer I don't think so, all what I have is what you see.

Comment: @AlokSwain nope, that's my mistake, updated

Comment: @mr_muscle You don't think so or did you check?
Add `Rails.logger.debug params[:original_message_id]` in your controller and check which value has params[:original_message_id]. Then check if you have record with such id in your rails console

Comment: Please post the full backtrace of the error. Right not its difficult to tell where the error originated from.

Comment: @TiSer but it's nothing new - `params[:original_message_id] = nil`

Comment: @mr_muscle do you understand overall what you want to have inside your `if original_message` condition at the `#create` action?
You should pass `original_message_id` in your params when you making request, so Rails will be able to find `original_message` object. Currently your `original_message` is `nil`, because `params[:original_message_id]` is nil (you do not pass anything valid in params).

Comment: In another words, you should pass `original_message_id` as parameter in your `form_for` at the `new.html.erb`.

Comment: @mr_muscle hello? Do you still need an answer on your question or could it be closed?